# How can I specify a default value for a system property in a Java web app?

Tags: java, properties, jetty, embedded-jetty

It seems like this should be so easy, but I have been banging my head on it for days.

I have a simple Java web app that uses Jetty embedded in an executable jar, and I am using system properties to define configuration info that I'm keeping separated from the app. I like that I can set system properties on the command line with `-D`.  For example,

```
java -Dbackend=backend_url -jar ...
```

Is there a way to set a *default* value for such a system property?

Answer (score 0):

If you are the one doing the reading of those properties. when you read them you can specify what is their default (in case they were not given via the cmd).

you can read about it here:
[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)